# How to show div after if function using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a div that is initially hidden

```html
<div class="create_member" style="position:absolute; display:none;" >
```

I want to unhide it when my variable is "1". I currently have this code but it does not unhide the div.

```php
<?php
if ($choice == "1"){
   ?>
   <style type="text/css">.create_member{
   display:block;
   }</style>
   <?php
   create_member($address_book);
}
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `!important` property to override the existing style.

```
if ($choice == "1"){
   ?>
   <style type="text/css">
   .create_member{ display:block !important; }
    </style>
   <?php
   create_member($address_book);
}
```